# Having a number go through 3 numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am currently trying to do an assignment for my programming class and the assignment requires I create a range between 1-10 and input a number in that range. After the input is given the number will be multiplied by the first number in an array of 3 numbers (19, 85, 2). so say I put in the number 2. It would than be multiplied by 19. After the first calculation it will subtract the second element in the array from the total of the first calculation, and after that it will divide the second calculation by the third element in the array. I do not know how to have a number go through separate elements of the same array. Right now I can get the number I input to multiply but it multiplies with all 3 numbers in the array instead of the first.

```
def multiply( array , n ): 
    unumb = 0
    while 1 > unumb or 10 < unumb:
     try:
         unumb = int(input("Please enter a number (1 - 10) : "))
     except ValueError:
        print ("That wasn't an integer in range")
    for i in range(n): 
        unumb = unumb * array[i] 
    return unumb

  

array = [19, 85, 2] 
n = len(array) 

print(multiply(array, n))
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number (1 - 10) : 2
6460
```

Comment: Python **3.0**? RLY?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're doing a different thing with each element of the array, it doesn't really make sense to iterate over it -- just access the elements with `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: "))
        if x not in range(1, 11):
            raise ValueError("That wasn't an integer in range")
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

a = [19, 85, 2]
print(f"Result: {(x * a[0] - a[1]) / a[2]}")
```

Comment: Whenever explicit list indexes are used, it may be a good case for a dictionary too!

Comment: thank you so much this worked. he didn't go over arrays a whole lot in our notes.

Comment: @ti7 agree; this is a terrible assignment for learning how lists work, lol

Comment: try having a professor who leaves out big parts of info in his notes cuz he thinks he would help us to much.

Comment: @JustinSinger it sounds a bit mysterious and well off-topic, but it may help to consider Python a big wrapper to make C easier to use. Further, this elderly document is ever-relevant https://david.goodger.org/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Answer (score 0):

As you have to do three different calculations you don't need to iterate, also I noticed that you used a function structure, so I wrote something similar to your code.

```
def multiply(array):

    #Getting the input.
    unumb = int(input("Please insert a number between 1 and 10: "))

    if 1 <= unumb <= 10:

        unumb*=array[0]
        unumb-=array[1]
        #unumb/=array[2] #If you want a float result.
        unumb = int(unumb/array[2]) #If you want a int result.

        return unumb

    else: print("Not a number between 1 and 10.")


array = [19,85,2]
print(multiply(array))
```